# Matlab: Appending structure with new field dynamically in loop

Tags: matlab, loops, structure

I a bunch of data structures with an id `(id1, id2, id3, ... idN)` a single data field that contains variables `(var1,var2,var3, ... varK)`, such that the first structure looks like

```
id1.data.variable1 = []
id1.data.variable2 = []
.
.
.
```

All id's share the same data and variable structure.

Now, I would very much like to append a new variable (newvar) to these existing structures in a loop.

For one structure, I would just do this:

```
id1.data.newvar1 = id1.data.var1^2
```

which would add `newvar1` to my `id1.data` with `id1.data.var1^2` as values.

If i try

```
for i = 1:length(id_list)
      id_list{i}.data.newvar = id_list{i}.data.var1^2
end
```

I get a "Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object." error.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: you are referencing `id_list{i}` as if it were a cell array. The error is because you try to reference the contents of that cell array as if it were a structure.
What exactly is `id_list`? You might want to try `(id_list{i})` if `id_list` is the list of all field names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new global struct that contains the set of structs that you are working with. Thus, the new struct will have the following fields:

```
ID.id1, ID.id2, ..., ID.idnumber_of_ids
```

So, in order to loop each id#:

```
for i = 1:number_of_ids
    name = ['id' num2str(i)];
    ID.(name).data.newvar = ID.(name).data.var1^2;
end
```

Finally, save the struct without the ID high-level:

```
save('here.mat','-struct','ID');
```